# Numpy.delete() function not properly deleting element at index

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, data-structures

I'm facing a simple problem where I have to delete elements from a 2-dimensional `NumPy` array-like `m`. When I try to remove an element at a certain index with `delete()` function, it just doesn't perform the deletion.

```
import numpy as np

m = np.array([[1], [1], [3]])
np.delete(m, 2)

print(m)
```

This code is supposed to output `[[1], [1]]`, as it's deleting the element at index `2`. But the actual output it gives is the same original array `[[1] [1] [3]]`.

- Why is this function not working?
- And how can I solve it without converting the NumPy array to a Python list?

Answer (score 1):

It's because [delete](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) function, returns a copy of changed array.
You need to do this:

```
import numpy as np

m = np.array([[1], [1], [3]])
m = np.delete(m, 2)
print(m)
```

In according to numpy documentation: Return a new array with sub-arrays along an axis deleted.

Comment: Yes, but it's not dimensional consistent `[1 1]`. It should return `[[1], [1]]` The shape of the output is `(2,)` but it should be `(2, 1)`

Comment: Right, you can set axis. If you want get 2D shape, axis value will be (0).

Answer (score 0):

Referring  numpy documentation for np.delete :-

*Returns out - ndarray
A copy of arr with the elements specified by obj removed. Note that delete does not occur in-place. **If axis is None, out is a flattened array**.*

Correct code is

```html
import numpy as np

m = np.array([[1], [1], [3]])
m = np.delete(m, 2,0)

print(m)
```

Output:

**[[1]
[1]]**